# Show that Hilbert-Schmidt inner product is an inner product

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, trace

I have to show that the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product is an inner product for complex and hermitian $d\times d$ Matrices
$$(A,B)=Tr(A^\dagger B)$$ I checked [the wolfram page for the definition of an inner product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InnerProduct.html)
The first two and the last property are relatively easy to show, but I am stuck with the third property:
$$(A,B)=(B,A)^*$$
For hermitian matrices I tried to show it in the following way:
$$(A,B)^*=(Tr(A^\dagger B))^*=Tr((A^\dagger B)^*)=Tr((A^\dagger)^* B^*))$$

Comment: Note that for numbers, complex conjugation is the same as conjugate transpose so $(A,B)^* = tr(A^\dagger B)^* = tr(A^\dagger B)^\dagger = tr ( [ A^\dagger B ]^\dagger ) = tr ( B^\dagger A) = (B,A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use the fact that $$\operatorname{Tr}(A)=\operatorname{Tr}(A^T)$$ This would lead, from your last step, to

$$\operatorname{Tr}((A^\dagger)^*B^*) = \operatorname{Tr}(A^TB^*) = \operatorname{Tr}((A^TB^*)^T) = \operatorname{Tr}((B^*)^TA) = \operatorname{Tr}(B^\dagger A) = (B,A)$$

which is the result you were searching for.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.